# GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem keeps logging "Successfully repaired ... directory"

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-storage

I have an Apache Spark application writing to GCS. For every write we get a log like this:

```
c.g.c.h.r.g.c.g.c.h.g.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem: Successfully repaired 'gs://.../...' directory.
```

I guess it's succeeding, so that's great? And everything works. But why does it need to repair everything?

Comment: Can you please try setting --properties=spark.hadoop.fs.gs.implicit.dir.repair.enable=false

Comment: its recreating directory markers. if you can turn it off with cayman's suggestion, it'll be saving on IO as well as keeping the logs quieter